# Google MyBusiness API working in localhost, but not in hosting server

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api

My employer has a project approved for Google MyBusiness Api. GMB Api is used to manage locations on Google and its reviews.

The problem I'm facing is that I can get the reviews in localhost, but when I try it in my main hosting server, no reviews are returned. The rest of the Apis like getting accounts and locations work fine, only getting the reviews does not work.

Is there something that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a temporary issue. Everything is good now.